# How to set icon for Mathematica in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux

I installed Mathematica 9 and 10 on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 with Unity.  How to set icons for them?  At the moment they show up as gray squares with a question mark in it on the dock.

Answer (score 4):

Well I solved it this way:

Go to:

`/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources/X/`

(or wherever your local mathematica installation is located)

From there move the 32x32, 64x64 and 128x128 .png icon files into the respective

`/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps`

folders, but giving them respectively the same name (such as wolfram-mathematica9.png).

Then edit the file:

/usr/share/applications/wolfram-mathematica9.desktop

change the line corresponding to Icon:

`Icon=wolfram-mathematica9`

(without the png extension)

If that file is not present in /usr/share, copy it from here:

`/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Installation/wolfram-mathematica9.desktop`

Remember: You need sudo permissions to run these commands.

To be sure, you can run

`sudo updatedb`

then reboot and it should work now.

Comment: That doesn't work for MMA 10.4.1 under Linux Mint 17.3 Cinammon. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Mathematica 10.4.1.0 on Ubuntu seems to have proper icon from the start.

Comment: I wanted to start Mma directly from the whiskermenu rather than from there through another submenu with only a single choice. Clicking on the left upper square in Xfce's launcher properties, setting command to /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/Executables/Mathematica %F and the symbol to  /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/wolfram-mathematica.png worked fine for me. Thank you for this hint. I would not have searched in /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps - what a long path! How did you get that?

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen that's the standard directory where third-party applications put their icons.